# How to print a database table in html (simple)

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

This may be a simple question however I would appreciate the help as I am new to PHP and mysql.

How do I print one of the tables from my phpmyAdmin database into my site, what is the code to do so? The database table is constantly updating with new entries so how do I ensure that the website table will update with new entries as well.

I know there have been similar questions however answers are all in outdated code (mysql). I would appreciate the help !

Comment: Way too broad. Learn PHP and MySQL. Any tutorial will show you how to do this. It's actually very easy.

Comment: I have searched it up as I have said however the code is using mysql which is outdated and doesn't work.

Comment: why not search for an example that explicitly supports php 5.6 ?

Comment: Mysql itself is not outdated. The `mysql_` driver/functions are. Here's a thread on the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928604/php-and-mysqli-html-table-from-database.

Comment: I will look at w3schools, I was making a simple mistake by closing the connection to early. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP file:

```
<?php
// connect to your database

// run query to select everything
$sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sel)){
    echo $row['column_1']." ".$row['column_2']."<br>";
}
?>
```

Replace the table_name => with the table from you want to select all data.
Replace the column_1/2 => with your column names.

For another problem I am here to help in the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already know the column names in the table you want to output, you can pull them from the database schema with another query and merge the two data sets together later on. Here's a working example:

```
$db_name = "DATABASE_NAME_GOES_HERE";
$table_name = "TABLE_NAME_GOES_HERE";

$db = new mysqli("DB_HOSTNAME","DB_USERNAME","DB_PASSWORD",$db_name);

$columns = array();
$q = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='".$db_name."' AND TABLE_NAME='".$table_name."';";
$r = mysqli_query($db,$q);
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r) ) {
    $columns[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
    }

$q = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name.";";
$r = mysqli_query($db,$q);

// spit out the table
echo "<table><tr>";
foreach( $columns as $col ) {
    echo "<th>".$col."</th>";
    }
echo "</tr>";
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r) ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach( $columns as $col ) {
        echo "<td>".$row[$col]."</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```